# jQuery returning wrong count of JSON objects

Tags: jquery, json

I'm iterating through some JSON and outputting the count of a particular item.  So when a user selects an option from a drop down, it displays the number of it's immediate children.

```
 $('#dataCombo').change(function () {
     $('#OutputDisplay').html('');
     var values = $('#dataCombo').val();
     var parsedData = JSON.parse($retrievedData);
     for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
         var count = parsedData.genres[i].publishers.length;
         $('#OutputDisplay').append("<p>" + values[i] + "</p><br/><p>Publisher Count: " + count + " total</p>")
     }
 });
```

Currently the code above (almost) produces what i want, it shows the number of publishers in the genre.  However the value returned doesn't depend on what has been selected.

So for example

`Genre 1 has 3 publishers
Genre 2 has 5 publishers
Genre 3 had 10 publishers.`

If i select `genre 1` then `2` then `3` the count displayed is correct.

If i select `genre 2` first (or `genre 3`) then the count is wrong (it shows 3).  So it looks like it's iterating through the JSON regardless of what is selected.

Any ideas how i return the count for the specifically selected item?

Comment: Where is `$retrievedData` coming from? Is this wrapped in an async callback?

Comment: It's a global variable, retrieved from a Ajax request, the data request is fine, i think it's to do with the  `var count = parsedData.genres[i].publishers.length;`

Comment: What does `console.dir(parsedData);` return (try with Chrome)?

Comment: It returns all my JSON (too much to post), `console.dir($parsedData);` did anyway, with the `$`